# How to get a Export Complete Event in Jquery DataTable Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get a Complete Event after Clicking on Export Button of Jquery DataTable.
Intention is to add a Loading Icon on Click of Export Button and Hide Loading Icon on Export Completion.

```
$("#Summary_TotalPatientsDataTable").DataTable({
 buttons: ['excelHtml5'],
});
```

This will code will export the Table to Excel Format But i need a 'completion' event after the Export is done.

Comment: Can you provide us the relevant code you wrote (and at least what you've tried so far) for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Required a completion event after the Export is done